# Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32

Tags: usb

I have a laptop E5470 and it only has 1 USB controller. My usecase is adding USB external drives. As of now, I am able to support more than 32 devices on a single controller.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 35, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 39, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 36, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 29, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 38, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 28, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 41, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 34, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 33, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 22, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 27, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 32, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 19, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 25, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 42, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 37, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 40, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 30, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 24, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 4: Dev 31, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
                |__ Port 2: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 50, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 51, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 52, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 53, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
```

Now, when I added a new USB controller via (replacing my wifi card and putting in a m2 to mini PCI adapter, and then adding my own mini PCI adapter), it was assigned Bus 4. I get the following (I'm able to add some devices)

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 19, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 22, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 24, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
```

Now, when I attempt to add more USB devices to Bus 4, I am getting the error. I don't understand.. My Bus 2 USB controller has more devices than my Bus 4.. Yet Bus 4 complains it cant add more devices? How come?

I'm expecting Bus 4 to hold the same amount of devices as Bus 2, but it is erroring out

```
[  733.095066] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[  733.095081] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 32.
[  733.095092] usb 4-2.1-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

How do I find out why Unix is not allowing me to add more devices to a controller? `lsusb` doesnt give more information like whats the limit of a particular controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is incorrect. Not all USB XHCI controllers are the same, although they all present a similar, standardized programming interface.

[You can easily find the base XHCI specification on the internet.](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf)

In Chapter 5.3, starting from page 380, is a description of *Host Controller Capability Registers*, which tell the driver what are the capabilities of the particular implementation of XHCI controller. Subchapter 5.3.3 describes a read-only *Structural Parameters 1* register, which contains the maximum number of device slots, interrupters, and ports this specific controller can handle.

Your Bus 4 controller has a different hardware implementation of XHCI from your Bus 2, and so they apparently have different maximum numbers of devices they can handle.

The command

```
lspci -nnvd ::0c03
```

should print out enough information to allow you to identify the exact XHCI controller chips used. You can then google for their datasheets to confirm their capabilities, if you don't believe me.